# Removing character from specific length

Tags: r, numbers, element, string-length, removing-whitespace

I have a column as bellow:

```
a)1902-2019: -1.05 mm/yr
b)1902-1961: -0.79 mm/yr
c)1962-2019: -1.43 mm/yr
```

I want to remove character to be as flow:

```
a)1902-2019
b)1902-1961
c)1962-2019
```

Would you mind to help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
x <- '1962-2019: -1.43 mm/yr'
gsub(':.*', "", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `substr`.

```
df1 <- transform(df1, V3=substr(V1, 1, 9))
df1
#                       V1         V2        V3
# 1 1902-2019: -1.05 mm/yr  1.1088551 1902-2019
# 2 1902-1961: -0.79 mm/yr -0.1593216 1902-1961
# 3 1962-2019: -1.43 mm/yr  0.5811273 1962-2019
```

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("1902-2019: -1.05 mm/yr", "1902-1961: -0.79 mm/yr", 
"1962-2019: -1.43 mm/yr"), V2 = c(0.0958290168309483, 2.00653802357232, 
0.961576240476421)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to extract everything until a colon (`:`)

```
sub('(.*):.*', '\\1', df$V1)
#[1] "1902-2019" "1902-1961" "1962-2019"
```